# Received error when using LISTAGG in my code

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing an error from my query:

```
select
    ES.SHPMNT_REF as "SHIPMENT REF",
    listagg(OH.ONHAND_REF,' ')within group(order by ES.SHPMNT_REF) as "test",
    SO.LOAD as "PORT OF LOADING",
    SO.DSCHRG_CITY as "DEST"
from 
    BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES 
    left outer join BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS SO on ES.SHPMNT_REF = SO.SHPMNT_REF 
    left outer join BRDB.EXPORT_ONHAND OH on ES.SHPMNT_REF = OH.SHPMNT_REF
where 
    ES.REVENUE_ID = 'G2402467' 
    and ES.SHIPMENT_TYPE in ('EDO','EHO')
group by ES.SHPMNT_REF
```

Below is the error I received:

> An expression starting with "DSCHRG_CITY" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.. SQLCODE=-119, SQLSTATE=42803, DRIVER=4.19.49. 2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2".

I am not sure why this happened, but if I removed "SO.LOAD" and "SO.DSCHRG_CITY" then the coding worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't select non aggregate columns in a `GROUP BY` query.  What is your expected output?

Comment: you cant list values in the select statement that arent "grouped" and aren't in the group by clause

Comment: Guys i have added the expression i received, please assist

Comment: The error tells you what the second comment told you. You cant have SO.LOAD in the select if you don't have it in the group by clause. The same with SO.DSCHRG_CITY

Comment: Put SO.LOAD and SO.DSCHRG_CITY into GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Isn't that a DB2 error message? Are you sure you're working with Oracle? (The problem and the solution are the same, it just seems strange...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using group

```
select
  ES.SHPMNT_REF as "SHIPMENT REF",
  listagg(OH.ONHAND_REF,' ')within group(order by ES.SHPMNT_REF) as "test",
  min(SO.LOAD) as "PORT OF LOADING",
  ming(SO.DSCHRG_CITY) as "DEST"
from BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES 
left outer join BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS SO on 
  ES.SHPMNT_REF = SO.SHPMNT_REF 
left outer join BRDB.EXPORT_ONHAND OH 
  on ES.SHPMNT_REF = OH.SHPMNT_REF
where ES.REVENUE_ID = 'G2402467' and ES.SHIPMENT_TYPE in ('EDO','EHO')
group by ES.SHPMNT_REF
```

with grouping

```
select
  ES.SHPMNT_REF as "SHIPMENT REF",
  listagg(OH.ONHAND_REF,' ')within group(order by ES.SHPMNT_REF) as "test",
  SO.LOAD as "PORT OF LOADING",
  SO.DSCHRG_CITY as "DEST"
from BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES 
left outer join BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPPING_ORDERS SO on 
  ES.SHPMNT_REF = SO.SHPMNT_REF 
left outer join BRDB.EXPORT_ONHAND OH 
  on ES.SHPMNT_REF = OH.SHPMNT_REF
where ES.REVENUE_ID = 'G2402467' and ES.SHIPMENT_TYPE in ('EDO','EHO')
group by ES.SHPMNT_REF, SO.Load, SO.DSCHRG_CITY
```

Comment: Hi Simonare, I found that the column "test" will have duplicate data if using the "Without using group", do you know how to solve it? Thanks.